# D3.js category color scale not working properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I have one view that creates paths and I'm trying to have it so that each line that I draw has a random color.

I'm currently doing this-

```
            var color = d3.scale.category20();


                //other code that does stuff 
        this.path = svg.append("path")
            .attr("d", line(newData))
            .style("stroke", function(d,i) { 
                var colorIndex = Math.random() * (20 - 0) + 0;
                return color(colorIndex); })
            .attr("fill","none")
            .attr("class","line");
```

This does not draw lines with different colours. Further, when I do this

```
        this.path = svg.append("path")
            .attr("d", line(newData))
            .style("stroke", function(d,i) { 
                return color(4); })
            .attr("fill","none")
            .attr("class","line");
```

The color is still blue.

Why is that happening?

Comment: would be helpful if you could create a jsfiddle..

Comment: I could - there's just a lot of dependent stuff - creating a jsfiddle would take a ton of time

Comment: possible give us fiddle

Comment: in any case - hard coding the return color(4) should not be returning the same color as returning color(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because domain was not set -

[d3.scale.category10() not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590396/d3-scale-category10-not-behaving-as-expected)

has the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have set up a minimal fiddle to show you the proper way to set up the line function. I also changed the color scheme to category(10) to show more contrasting colors (you can still use category20 and see a difference in colors though). Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kne8L/).

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {
        return d.x;
    })
        .y(function (d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .interpolate("linear");
```

Comment: @praks5432 Is this what you were looking for?