# Color scale not working appropriately in D3/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Im using a color scale :

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();
```

Im using this to color the edges of a force layout graph according to their value

```
var links = inner.selectAll("line.link")
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.label); });
```

Now I need a 'legend' to show the user what each color means:

```
    edgesArray = [];
    edgesArrayIndex = [];
    for (i=0;i<data.edges.length;i++) {
    if(!edgesArray[data.edges[i].name])
    {
    edgesArray[data.edges[i].name]=1;
    edgesArrayIndex.push(data.edges[i].name);       
    }
}

var colourWidth = 160;
var colourHeight = 25;

for(i=0; i<edgesArrayIndex.length; i++){

if (edgeColour == true){    
svg.append('rect')
    .attr("width",  colourWidth)
    .attr("height", colourHeight)
    .attr("x", Marg*2)
    .attr("y", Marg*2 + [i]*colourHeight)   
    .style("fill", color(i))
    ;
svg.append("text")  
    .attr("x", Marg*3)
    .attr("y", Marg*2 + [i]*colourHeight + colourHeight/2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(color(i) + " : " + data.edges[i].name); 
}
//console.log(edgesArrayIndex);
}
```

The colors are all wrong. When I attach the colors to the graph the first 6 colors get attached to the edges as there are 6 different types of edges.

But when I apply the color scale to the 6 'rects' I appended to the SVG its as if the first 6 colors of the color scale array got used up when applying then to the edges and when i do the for loop starting at color(0) it actually gives me the color at color(5) (as 0 is first).

For example, say ive got red,blue,green,white,black,pink,orange,yellow,indigo,aqua.
My edges get - red,blue,green,white,black,pink
and now when i want to apply the scale to the rects I made, I would expect the rects to have the same values - red,blue,green,white,black,pink.

But they actually have : orange,yellow,indigo,aqua, red, blue.

They start at color[5] and its as if they wrap round to the beginning and go back to red, blue and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different parts of the data for the colour scale -- first the label, then the name. By definition, this will give you different colours (different inputs map to different outputs as far as possible given the output range).

To get the same colours, pass in the same attributes, e.g. the labels (if I understood your data structure correctly):

```
svg.append('rect')
   .style("fill", color(data.edges[i].label))
```

Comment: appreciate you looking through my long question and code, but that was a typo on my part. I edited the code before putting it on here as I can't show my code so I'm afraid that's not the issue :(:( could you think of anything that may be wrong ? @Lars Kotthoff

Comment: never mind this question helped - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590396/d3-scale-category10-not-behaving-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

this question helped me -

[d3.scale.category10() not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590396/d3-scale-category10-not-behaving-as-expected)

basically you have to put a domain on the scale. So instead of

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();
```

Change it to:

```
var color = d3.scale.category10().domain([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);//-colour scale
```